# Nextgen gallery title and description on thumbnail (Wordpress Plugin)

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

How can I show nextgen gallery thumbnail title and description? I tried to find it in the gallery settings but it seems it was not included there.

Answer (score 2):

I see that a lot of people are struggling with this, so I will share my solution in very simple terms, but in an "understandable" way:

Just make a copy of your `gallery.php` file (located within the `view` folder which is located in the Next Gen Gallery directory; the path is something like: `YOURDOMAIN.COM/WORDPRESS_INSTALATION_FOLDER/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/ngglegacy/view/GALLERY.PHP)`

Let's name it `gallery-new.php`. Open the file with any text editor or Sublime, and paste this echo to the title and description (just paste it below this line):

```
<div class="ngg-galleryoverview" id="<?php echo $gallery->anchor ?>">

<?php echo $gallery->title ?> <br>
<?php echo $gallery->description ?>
```

You can also add a "Go Back to Galleries" button by adding a very basic line of code:

```
<a href="http://yourdomain.com/galleries"> Go Back</a>
```

Save your file and upload it.

HERE IS THE "TRICK":

Log in into WordPress, in the dashboard, select the `Gallery` icon (Next Gen Gallery's icon, more specifically `> GALLERY SETTINGS > NEXT GEN BASIC THUMBNAILS`).

And here is the **simple** solution: just select your template in the `TEMPLATE` menu (right below `Show Slideshow`), in this case select `gallery-new.php`, then save the changes and you're done! :)

Answer (score 0):

I’ll be glad to help.

From Nextgen

> Gallery > Gallery Setting > Basic thumbnails

look for the “Select View control and choose “caption-view”, this control is also in the “customize display settings” tab at the top when inserting a basic thumbnails gallery.

This will place the captions under each thumbnail.

Thanks